# Crystal Report Loading Issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have deploy crystal report at live server. That report working properly at my place local machine.

When I upload over live server it is asking me for server log-in detail so I have write code as per below

```
        Dim I As Integer
        Dim LogonInfo As String()
        Dim Server As String = "", Database As String = "", User As String = "", Pwd As String = ""
        LogonInfo = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString.Split(";")
        For i = 0 To LogonInfo.Length - 1
            Dim strTemp As String() = LogonInfo(i).Split("=")
            Select Case strTemp(0).ToLower()
                Case "server"
                    Server = strTemp(1)
                    Exit Select
                Case "database"
                    Database = strTemp(1)
                    Exit Select
                Case "user id"
                    User = strTemp(1)
                    Exit Select
                Case "password"
                    Pwd = strTemp(1)
                    Exit Select
            End Select
        Next
        CRViewer.ReportSource = rptName

        Dim myConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
        myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Database
        myConnectionInfo.UserID = User
        myConnectionInfo.Password = Pwd
        myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = True
        Dim myTableLogOnInfos As TableLogOnInfos = CRViewer.LogOnInfo()
        For Each myTableLogOnInfo As TableLogOnInfo In myTableLogOnInfos
            myTableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo
        Next
```

Still it is asking for credential .
What could be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

may be this will help you .

```
protected void Default()
{
    string _strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnectionStringBuilder _sqlcon = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_strConn);
    myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = _sqlcon.DataSource;
    myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = _sqlcon.InitialCatalog;
    myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = _sqlcon.UserID;
    myLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = _sqlcon.Password;
    rptClients.LogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfos();
    rptClients.LogOnInfo.Add(myLogOnInfo);
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have some extension methods for CR that I've written in VB.Net that might help you.  I usually don't use the viewer, but as long as you have access to the ReportDocument this will do the trick:

The extensions and examples on using them (typically I use an ADO connection with these):

http://www.blakepell.com/Main/BlogEntry.aspx?EntryID=e2fcdcf9-312e-4911-8572-20178c94660b